# quick sort implementation using python, can't figure out where I'm wrong in the implementation

Tags: python, quicksort

Below is the code that I'm implementing for quick sort in python. But I'm not able to get where I'm going wrong with the implementation. Any leads?

```
def quicksort(arr, size):
    partition(arr, size)

def partition(arr, size):
    if size <= 1:
        return

    left = 0
    right = size - 1
    pivot = arr[size/2]

    while left < right:
        while arr[left] < pivot:
            left += 1
        while arr[right] > pivot:
            right -= 1

        temp = arr[left]
        arr[left] = arr[right]
        arr[right] = temp

    partition(arr, left)
    partition(arr[left:], len(arr[left:]))
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,45,3,5,4,6]  
quicksort(arr, len(arr))
```

Comment: When posting questions, please describe the problem you're seeing - is the code throwing a runtime error? Does it run, but produce an unexpected result?

Comment: there seems to some problem with the implementation. I don't get the sorted list after running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting new slices:

```
partition(arr[left:], len(arr[left:]))
```

Those slices are *new lists*, not the original list object. Anything you do to those won't be visible in the original value of `arr`.

If you want to do the sorting in-place, you'll need to pass along start and stop values of what section of the array to sort, not pass along slices:

```
def quicksort(arr):
    partition(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1)

def partition(arr, start, stop):
    if stop - start < 1:
        return

    left = start
    right = stop
    pivot = arr[start + ((stop - start) / 2)]

    while left <= right:
        while arr[left] < pivot:
            left += 1
        while arr[right] > pivot:
            right -= 1

        if left <= right:
            arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[left]
            left += 1
            right -= 1

    partition(arr, start, right)
    partition(arr, left, stop)
```

I've made a few more tweaks, adjusting the boundary tests and using tuple assignment to swap the two elements.

This version sorts correctly:

```
>>> def quicksort(arr):
...     partition(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1)
... 
>>> def partition(arr, start, stop):
...     if stop - start < 1:
...         return
...     left = start
...     right = stop
...     pivot = arr[start + ((stop - start) / 2)]
...     while left <= right:
...         while arr[left] < pivot:
...             left += 1
...         while arr[right] > pivot:
...             right -= 1
...         if left <= right:
...             arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[left]
...             left += 1
...             right -= 1
...     partition(arr, start, right)
...     partition(arr, left, stop)
... 
>>> arr = [1,2,3,4,5,45,3,5,4,6]  
>>> quicksort(arr)
>>> arr
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 45]
```